# Pivoting with Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a set of records showing the status of implementation of software components. Each row has a feature area, a feature within that area, the product where that feature appears, and its implementation status (green, red, or yellow), like this:

| Feature_Area | Feature | Product | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User experience | Sign Up | App1 | Green |
| User experience | Sign Up | App2 | Red |
| User experience | Log off | App1 | Green |
| User experience | Log off | App2 | Red |
| Back End | Update User | App3 | Green |
| Back End | Delete User | App3 | Red |

I'd like to pivot this as shown here:
[image]

Specifically, I'd like:

1. A single row for each feature and columns for each app to show the status of that feature
2. Don't repeat the same feature area value over and over in the first column

I tried using the below, which got me a column for each app. I couldn't figure out how to group properly with this to get the output I was looking for. I'd welcome any ideas.

```
case when Product = 'App1' then title end as App1,
case when Product = 'App2' then title end as App2,
case when Product = 'App3' then title end as App3
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on provided description I suggest to group by `feature_area` and `feature` and select arbitrary value in group (or maybe `array_agg` if you anticipate different ones) (note, I used Presto/Trino specific [`if`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#id0) for concise syntax instead of `case`):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(Feature_Area, Feature, Product, Status) as (
    values ('User experience', 'Sign Up', 'App1', 'Green'),
        ('User experience', 'Sign Up', 'App2', 'Red'),
        ('User experience', 'Log off', 'App1', 'Green'),
        ('User experience', 'Log off', 'App2', 'Red'),
        ('Back End', 'Update User', 'App3', 'Green'),
        ('Back End', 'Delete User', 'App3', 'Red')
)

-- query
select Feature_Area,
       Feature,
       arbitrary(if(Product = 'App1', Status)) App1,
       arbitrary(if(Product = 'App2', Status)) App2,
       arbitrary(if(Product = 'App3', Status)) App3
from dataset
group by Feature_Area, Feature
order by Feature_Area desc, Feature desc;
```

Output:

| Feature_Area | Feature | App1 | App2 | App3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User experience | Sign Up | Green | Red | NULL |
| User experience | Log off | Green | Red | NULL |
| Back End | Update User | NULL | NULL | Green |
| Back End | Delete User | NULL | NULL | Red |

Comment: Thanks, @Guru, this was close to what I am looking for. I was hoping to also find a solution that satisfied #2 above ("Don't repeat the same feature area value over and over in the first column"). How would I do that?